# ArcGIS Pro Sort based on more then one field?

Tags: arcgis-pro, sorting

I want to sort attribute table based on more then one column.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open Attribute Table
2. Right click on any field name
3. Custom sort
4. Add Fields and Sort Type